# Set columns width in google chart table

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I make json to make google chart table as follows.

```
 var dataArray = '{
 "cols":[
     {"id":"name","label":"Name","type":"string","p":"{style: 'width: 200px;'}"},
     {"id":"date","label":"Date","type":"date","p":"{style: 'width: 200px;'}"}
 ],
 "rows":[.....
```

The rows has some value. I try to use p to set width of columns. But it is not work. I am referring https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam

It show syntax error. `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`

How can i change column with in google chart table? Please help me.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam

Answer (score 0):

Your `dataArray` is interpreted as a string. Remove the beginning quote to define your object:

```js
var dataArray = {
    //...
};
```